# virbr0 package not installed - qemu/kvm

Tags: debian, networking, kvm, qemu, bridge

I am trying to test a custom kernel configuration using qemu/kvm

when I do `$ virsh --connect qemu:///system net-start default` this is the output i get.

```
error: Failed to start network default
error: Unable to create bridge virbr0: Package not installed
```

I am unable to find a resource for this particular issue online, It would be really helpfull if someone can help me solve this issue.

I am using Debian 10 (Buster) with `5.8.4-rc4-next-20200710`. Thank you in advanve :)

UPDATE:
`apt search libvirt`
gives the following output

```
$ apt search libvirt
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
archipel-agent-hypervisor-network/stable 0.6.0-1 all
  Virtual Machine Orchestration (Agent Hypervisor Network)

bit-babbler/stable 0.8 amd64
  BitBabbler hardware TRNG and kernel entropy source support

gir1.2-libvirt-glib-1.0/stable,now 1.0.0-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
  GObject introspection files for the libvirt-glib library

gir1.2-libvirt-sandbox-1.0/stable,now 0.5.1+git20160404-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
  GObject introspection files for the libvirt-sandbox library

libnss-libvirt/stable 5.0.0-4+deb10u1 amd64
  nss plugin providing IP address resolution for virtual machines

libsanlock-client1/stable,now 3.6.0-3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
  Shared storage lock manager (client library)

libsys-virt-perl/stable,now 5.0.0-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
  Perl module providing an extension for the libvirt library

libvirt-clients/stable,now 5.0.0-4+deb10u1 amd64 [installed]
  Programs for the libvirt library

libvirt-daemon/stable,now 5.0.0-4+deb10u1 amd64 [installed]
  Virtualization daemon

libvirt-daemon-driver-storage-gluster/stable,now 5.0.0-4+deb10u1 amd64 [installed]
  Virtualization daemon glusterfs storage driver

libvirt-daemon-driver-storage-rbd/stable,now 5.0.0-4+deb10u1 amd64 [installed]
  Virtualization daemon RBD storage driver

libvirt-daemon-driver-storage-zfs/stable,now 5.0.0-4+deb10u1 amd64 [installed]
  Virtualization daemon ZFS storage driver

libvirt-daemon-system/stable,now 5.0.0-4+deb10u1 amd64 [installed]
  Libvirt daemon configuration files

libvirt-dbus/stable,now 1.3.0-1 amd64 [installed]
  libvirt D-Bus API bindings

libvirt-dev/stable,now 5.0.0-4+deb10u1 amd64 [installed]
  development files for the libvirt library

libvirt-doc/stable,now 5.0.0-4+deb10u1 all [installed]
  documentation for the libvirt library

libvirt-glib-1.0-0/stable,now 1.0.0-1 amd64 [installed]
  libvirt GLib and GObject mapping library

libvirt-glib-1.0-dev/stable,now 1.0.0-1 amd64 [installed]
  Development files for the libvirt-glib library

libvirt-ocaml/stable,now 0.6.1.4-2+b1 amd64 [installed]
  OCaml bindings for libvirt (runtime)

libvirt-ocaml-dev/stable,now 0.6.1.4-2+b1 amd64 [installed]
  OCaml bindings for libvirt (development files)

libvirt-sandbox-1.0-5/stable,now 0.5.1+git20160404-1 amd64 [installed]
  Application sandbox toolkit shared library

libvirt-sandbox-1.0-dev/stable,now 0.5.1+git20160404-1 amd64 [installed]
  Development files for libvirt-sandbox library

libvirt-sanlock/stable,now 5.0.0-4+deb10u1 amd64 [installed]
  Sanlock plugin for virtlockd

libvirt-wireshark/stable,now 5.0.0-4+deb10u1 amd64 [installed]
  Wireshark dissector for the libvirt protocol

libvirt0/stable,now 5.0.0-4+deb10u1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
  library for interfacing with different virtualization systems

libvirtodbc0/stable 6.1.6+dfsg2-4+b2 amd64
  high-performance database - ODBC libraries

libvirtualpg-dev/stable 2.0.0~rc0-1 amd64
  VirtualPG development files

libvirtualpg0/stable 2.0.0~rc0-1 amd64
  VirtualPG shared library

libvirtuoso5.5-cil/stable 6.1.6+dfsg2-4+b2 amd64
  high-performance database - Mono assemblies

mom/stable 0.5.12-1 all
  Dynamically manage system resources on virtualization hosts

munin-libvirt-plugins/stable 0.0.6-1 all
  Munin plugins using libvirt

nagios-plugins-contrib/stable 24.20190301 amd64
  Plugins for nagios compatible monitoring systems

nbdkit-plugin-libvirt/stable 1.10.3-1 amd64
  libvirt plugin for nbdkit

php-libvirt-php/stable 0.5.4-3 amd64
  libvirt bindings for PHP

python-libvirt/stable 5.0.0-1 amd64
  libvirt Python bindings

python3-libvirt/stable,now 5.0.0-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
  libvirt Python 3 bindings

resource-agents/stable 1:4.2.0-2+deb10u1 amd64
  Cluster Resource Agents

ruby-fog-libvirt/stable 0.6.0-1 all
  Module for the 'fog' gem to support libvirt

ruby-libvirt/stable 0.7.1-1 amd64
  Ruby bindings for libvirt

vagrant-libvirt/stable 0.0.45-2 all
  Vagrant plugin that adds an Libvirt provider to Vagrant

vagrant-mutate/stable 1.2.0-4 all
  convert vagrant boxes to work with different providers

vagrant-sshfs/stable 1.3.1-1 all
  vagrant plugin that adds synced folder support with sshfs

virt-goodies/stable 0.4-2.1 all
  A collection of helpful virtualisation related tools

virt-sandbox/stable 0.5.1+git20160404-1 amd64
  Application sandbox toolkit

virt-top/stable 1.0.8-2 amd64
  show stats of virtualized domains

virtinst/stable,now 1:2.0.0-3 all [installed]
  Programs to create and clone virtual machines
```

Comment: You need to install **libvirt-bin**.

Comment: ```libvirt-bin``` is not available, but is referred to by another package. I'm not able to find the package using ```apt search```

Comment: What does a search for **libvirt** return?

Comment: Hi, I've made a edit to the question which adds the search results to ```libvirt```. thanks

Comment: Hmmm...is the **libvirtd** service running? Have you tried running **virt-manager** to see if it can connect to the network?

Comment: Yes ```libvirtd``` service is running. Yes virt-manager was able to connect to the network.

Comment: Instead of `libvirt-bin` install `libvirt-daemon-system` and `libvirt-clients`. Source: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1089753/kvm-qemu-installation-issue-18-10

Comment: See https://serverfault.com/questions/1020323/libvirt-cannot-create-default-network